# Prove the von Staudt-Clausen congruence of the Bernoulli numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, bernoulli-numbers

I need to prove that:

If $p$ is prime greater than or equal to five, then $pB_{p-1}$ belongs to the p-integers and more over:

$$pB_{p-1} \equiv -1 \pmod p$$
Hint:Put $N=p$ in the Faulhaber´s formula: $S_{j}(N-1)=  \displaystyle\sum_{k=o}^j \frac{1}{(j-k+1)}{j \choose k}N^{j-k+1}B_{k}$ and reduce everything mod p and use the Fermat´s little theorem.

**But I do not know how to reduce this:  $S_{j}(p-1)=  \displaystyle\sum_{k=o}^j \frac{1}{(j-k+1)}{j \choose k}p^{j-k+1}B_{k}$ to mod p,and I have problems trying to prove that $pB_{p-1}$ belongs to the p-integers, Can you help to prove the theorem please, Thank you.**

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Staudt%E2%80%93Clausen_theorem.

Comment: Thank you @DietrichBurde do you mean the first lemma isnt it is because I got confuse because they say in the hypotesisis that :1. If p-1 divides 2n then,

 $\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}{(-1)^m{p-1\choose m} m^{2n}}\equiv{-1}\pmod p \!$ and my hypothesis are others :) Thank you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have problems with the proof of that $pB_{p-1}$ belongs to the p-integers. Can you help me thank you :)